# What spatial reference is used when setting Region in Grass?

Tags: grass-gis

I'm using Grass to process some data that is in UTM:43N. While creating the Location, it asked me for the Spatial reference, and I Entered the EPSG code for this Projection (EPSG:32643).

Now it's asking me to set the Region:

[image]

Do I enter the coordinates in EPSG:4326 (i.e. Lat Long), or in EPSG:32643 (UTM 43 N)?

Comment: In GRASS GIS, **one LOCATION = one Spatial reference**.

Comment: You set the region in UTM units. North will be the max extent of the region to the north, etc. And resolution will be in meters (units of UTM).

Answer (score 1):

You can even keep that region as-is and later modify it by setting it to a raster or vector map which you will import.

This region is the so-called computational region, for details see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region